# how to post anything else than strings with tweepy

Tags: python, python-2.7, tweepy

I'm trying to update my Twitter status with generated text. So far generating the text works well, but I cannot post to Twitter.

```
import tweepy

import SentenceGenerator

with open('Ratschlaege.txt','r') as textfile: #load the text to analyze
sample_text = textfile.read()

#Generating one sentence:
#print SentenceGenerator.generate_sentence(sample_text)

#Generating a paragraph:
sentences = 1
print ' '.join([SentenceGenerator.generate_sentence(sample_text) for i        in xrange(sentences)])


# Consumer keys and access tokens, used for OAuth
consumer_key = 'xxx'
consumer_secret = 'xxx'
access_token = 'xxx'
access_token_secret = 'xxx'

# OAuth process, using the keys and tokens
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)     
# Creation of the actual interface, using authentication
api = tweepy.API(auth)         
# Sample method, used to update a status
api.update_status(' '.join([SentenceGenerator.generate_sentence(sample_text) for i in xrange(sentences)]))
```

As far as I have found you can either post strings or from a file, but not the new generated text.
Is there any way?

——EDIT——
okay i tried to build a function inside my script like this

```
def tweet (tweet):
    tweet = ' '.join([SentenceGenerator.generate_sentence(sample_text) for i in xrange(sentences)])
    # Consumer keys and access tokens, used for OAuth
    consumer_key = 'xxx'
    consumer_secret = 'xxx'
    access_token = 'xxx'
    access_token_secret = 'xxx'

    # OAuth process, using the keys and tokens
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)     
    # Creation of the actual interface, using authentication
    api = tweepy.API(auth)         
    # Sample method, used to update a status
    api.update_status(tweet)        
time.sleep(10)
```

now it runs, every ten seconds in a loop (to test it out), and there is no error displayed but the status won't update. it runs like its supposed to do, only it doesn't tweet.
what am i missing??

——EDIT——

i also added a part that should insert the generated text into a MySQL db

```
db = MySQLdb.connect ( host ='127.0.0.1',
                       user = 'Daniel',
                       passwd = 'localhost')
        cur = db.cursor()
        cur.execute("insert into multigram (Ratschlag) value ('%s')" % (tweet))
```

Same here: No error message but also no entry in the db.
i am sure it's so simple to resolve, but i don't see what i am doing wrong.

Comment: What happens when you run this script? What is `SentenceGenerator`?

Comment: »SentenceGenerator« is another Pythonscript. It’s a Markov Chain which generates text. With this script you activate it and it prints out a generated sentence. Everything works fine, all i want to do is to tweet the generated sentence, an it does not work with the same command as print …

Comment: Hard to say without looking at `SentenceGenerator`, your tweepy code looks right. Maybe check into the output with `type` and printing to stdout?